# Python discord.py bot won't respond to a simple hello prompt

Tags: python, docker, amazon-ec2, discord, discord.py

I'm using an AWS EC2 instance to host the bot and docker to run it. [GitHub Link Here](https://github.com/Awesomefusion/LiandriDiscordBot)

I really can't figure out what the problem is as it should be straight-forward and simple.

**main**.py code is below:

```py
import os
import discord

class LiandriDiscordBot(discord.Client):
  """Liandri Discord Bot."""

intents = discord.Intents.default().all()
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.author == client.user:
    return
  msg = message.content
  if msg.startswith('hello'):
    await message.channel.send("hello!")

client.run(os.getenv("DISCORD_TOKEN"))
```

I tried to host the bot on my EC2 server and it is added, I then ran the bot using docker, used the discord developer portal to add it to my testing server and then try to type hello, expecting the bot to say hello back, but simply nothing happens.

Comment: check your indents

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue at some point, I think it was to do with the permissions of the bot. From https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/discord.html:

> Make sure you’re logged on to the Discord website.
>
> Navigate to the application page
>
> Click on your bot’s page.
>
> Go to the “OAuth2” tab.
>
> How the OAuth2 page should look like. Tick the “bot” checkbox under
> “scopes”.
>
> [image: The scopes checkbox with "bot" ticked.]
>
> Tick the permissions required for your bot to function under “Bot
> Permissions”.
>
> [image: The permission checkboxes with some permissions checked.]

Lmk if that works.